# How to compare 2 columns of different tables?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I need to populate a database, using csv files. A foreign key is implemented as `xid REFERENCES table1 NOT NULL`. Now I need to populate `xid` in the 2nd table with `cid` from the first table.

the tables are set up like this

**table1:**

```
xid SERIAL Primary KEY
country VARCHAR(256)
```

**table2:**

```
yid SERIAL Primary KEY 
building VARCHAR(256)
country VARCHAR(256)
xid REFERENCES country NOT NULL
```

I populated `table1` using the csv file. Now my problem is I cant get the `xid` into `table2`.
I am using python with `import csv` and `import psycopg2`

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating a temporary table for loading the data:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_building (building VARCHAR(256), country VARCHAR(256)) ON COMMIT DROP;
```

Load your data into this temporary table and then load up table2:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (building, country, xid)
SELECT building, country, xid
FROM table2
JOIN temp_building on temp_building.country = table2.country;
```

Then, commit your transaction and the temporary table will be dropped.

However, I'd strongly recommend against putting the country column into table2.  The data are already in table1, so don't duplicate them.